# From extended metric to extended norm

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

1. A metric $d$ has to verify the 4 axioms of separability, identity of indiscernibles, symmetry and sub-additivity, and takes value in $[0, +\infty[$.
2. I saw that it is possible to also extend the definition to the **extended positive real numbers** allowing for $d$ to take the value $+\infty$, where the axioms still make sense from the operations defined on these extended numbers.
3. Some metrics can be found to arise from a norm, by defining $d(x,y) = \|x - y\|$. For some metrics it is not the case, as for example when $d$ is bounded, it cannot be homogeneous.

So now I am wondering: Is it possible for an extended metric to arise from a norm ?

Comment: No. If $d(x, y)=\infty$ and $d(x, y)=\|x-y\|$ then, obviously, $\|x-y\|=\infty$. Set $h=x-y$. You are in trouble with homogeneity, because $\|h\|=\infty$ and also $\|\lambda h\|=|\lambda|\|h\|$, what will you do if $\lambda=0$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro No problem, define $0\cdot \infty = 0$, as it is routinely done in Lebesgue integration.

Comment: @JessicaMcRae: Ok, but then the operation $(\lambda, x)\in \mathbb R\times X\to \lambda x\in X$ is not continuous anymore. (Here I have let $X$ denote the normed space). You are free to make such definitions, of course. But there's a high price to pay.

Comment: Would it make sense to have a norm where homogeneity is only verified for scalars which are not the $0$ of the field in question ?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Just like you can define $0\cdot \infty=0$ you can define $0\cdot \infty=\infty$. You are confused about what the problem is.

Comment: @ippiki-ookami A norm is defined on a vector space. $[0,+\infty]$ is not an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. $d(0,1)$ would have to be $\|0-1\|$, but $0-1$ doesn't exist, is not an element of the space.

Comment: @JessicaMcRae: If you do that, then you lose the normed space axiom that $\|0\|=0$, because $\|0h\|=\infty$. Maybe I am confused, as you say, but I am firmly sure that introducing vectors of infinite length is not compatible with the axioms of normed space. (We discussed a construction that allows generalized vectors with infinite norm [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2474757/8157), for example. This is not strongly related with the present question, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, as long as we are making up definitions, let's go all the way. Let's say an extended norm is a thing that takes values in $[0, \infty]$ and still satisfies the [axioms of a norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition), where $0\cdot \infty$ is interpreted as $0$.

An extended norm induces an extended metric by $d(x, y) = \|x-y\|$.

An example of an extended norm would be $\|f\|=\int_X |f|$ on the space of all measurable functions on some measure space $X$. Another example is $\|x\| = \sup_n |x_n|$ on the space of all sequences $\{x_n\}$. One can use all kinds of familiar norms on function spaces and sequence spaces, allowing elements for which the norm is infinite.

I don't know what it gets us, besides having one more definition.